# Is there an EOL for specific minor versions of CentOS?

Tags: centos

The End-Of-Life for CentOS 7 [is scheduled for June 30, 2024](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product).

Are there specific EOLs for specific minor versions of CentOS 7, i.e. 7.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point releases effectively reach their end of life [as soon as the next point release on the same major branch is made available](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#How_does_CentOS_versioning_work.3F):

> The CentOS Project provides updates or other changes **ONLY** for the latest version of each major branch. Thus, if the latest minor version of CentOS-6 is version 6.6 then the CentOS Project only provides updated software for this minor version in the 6 branch. If you are using an older minor version than the latest in a given branch, then you are missing security and bugfix updates. Older minor versions are not supported in official support avenues.

If you keep your CentOS 7 system updated, you’ll upgrade to newer point releases seamlessly, so this shouldn’t be a concern in general unless you specifically need to stay on a given point release.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so - the major one staying the same contains the guarantee that anything that run with CentOS 7 at its release day will run with CentOS 7 until the EOL of it.

7.1 just says "I'm a CentOS 7, and I run on newer hardware and have added features and newer software in the following areas...", so there's no "support" that's "unique" to a minor version. So, there's no unique EOL, either.